# Euler Lagrange equation in variational calculus for a sum of integrals

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control, variational-analysis

Let $F, G: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow{}\mathbb{R}$ be two continuously differentiable functions and let $a\leq b \leq c$. I want to know if there exists some known method to find a function that maximizes the functional $J(P):=\int_a^b F(q,P(q),P'(q))dq+ \int_b^c G(q,P(q),P'(q))dq$ between all the continuously differentiable functions $P: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow{}\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $P(a)=0$.

Comment: Is it the case that $F(b,P(b),P'(b))=G(b,P(b),P'(b))$? If so and their derivatives also match at $b$ then you can define a piecwise $C^1$ function and use the Euler Lagrange  equations.

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Does $P$ satisfies any conditions at $b$ and/or $c$?

Comment: Yes: I need $F(b,P(b),P'(b))=0=G(c,P(c),P'(c))$

Comment: Those seem not necessary. Other conditions?

Answer (score -1):

This is known as a multiphase optimal control problem, and there is software available online for this kind of problems. Examples are DIDO (matlab, proprietary), GPOPS-II (matlab, proprietary), PROPT(matlab, proprietary - i think), ICLOCS2 (matlab, free) and PSOPT (C++, free).

They all use pseudospectral methods, which are great to feed a computer, but not very practical to solve by hand. I don't know any method to solve analytically. However, I am certain that if $F$ and $G$ are not identical, then the Hamiltonian will (most likely) have a jump discontinuity at q = b.